# Why is my script not waiting for networking service to start before running?

Tags: debian, startup

I am using Debian 8 and have configured a script and put it under /etc/init.d directory as below. Basically, I want to open ssh tunnels on startup.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/open_tunnels

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          open_tunnels
# Required-Start:    $network $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog 
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Running open_tunnels..."
    <ssh command>
    ;;
  stop)
    killall open_tunnels
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/open_tunnels start"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac


exit 0
```

Then I added the service with

```
insserv open_tunnels
```

But, when I start the system I got this on syslog:

```
open_tunnels[522]: ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Network is unreachable
```

I am sure the ssh command works well because I use it on my system (after login). I just want it to be executed on startup.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Have you checked this?: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/

Comment: @coffeMug, Yes, I have. I just added the 'networking' close to $network and it didn't work. I think there is something more I have to do in order to make sure my networking device is up and running before executing the script.

Comment: Did you also add K and S entries in the run-levels? `update-rc.d filename defaults`

Comment: Actually, I tried this command but I saw that now Debian 8 does that operation using insserv instead of update-rc.d.

Comment: Debian 8 is using systemd now; try to rewrite it as a systemd service.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ for an exhaustive treatment of the matter. You main problem is this:

> What precisely is required for `$network` is not obvious and can be different things depending on local configuration.

Systemd gives you better tools as detailed on the above link. Basically, you'll want to put

```
[Unit]
Require = network-online.target
After = network-online.target
```

in your custom service file and hope that your network management service provides a well-behaving `network-online.target`.

If you don't want to replace your init script with a systemd service file, create the `/etc/systemd/system/open_tunnels.service.d` directory and put the above 3 lines into any file (with `.conf` extension) in that directory. This will augment the service description autogenerated by the SysV init compatibility layer of systemd, as explained in `man systemd.unit`.

Comment: Ok, but this solution works if I write the script with systemd pointed by @Martin von Wittich, right? The syntax is a little different from what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't get your note about "the syntax", but writing a custom service file would be the best option. Failing that you can try the `service.d` method I've just added to my answer.